# Symfony 1.4 Action not being hit. Why?

Tags: symfony-1.4, url-routing

I'm working on an old project that needs some extra functionality. It uses symfony 1.4. I'm new to symfony.

There are 4 actions now:

executeAdmin, executeDashboard, executeHome, executeView that work well. They are in a file called action.class.php.

The routing looks like this (in routing.yml):

```
editor:
  url: /editor/:action/*
  param: { module: bookeditor }
```

It was my assumption that creating a new executeTest in the same action.class.php would work out of the box.

```
 private function executeUpload ( $request ) {
    $this->response->setContent("<h1>Ok!</h1>");
    return sfView::NONE;
 }
```

When going to mysite/editor/upload I get the 404 page.

If I replace the code of executeAdmin for example:

```
 private function executAdmin ( $request ) {
    $this->response->setContent("<h1>Ok!</h1>");
    return sfView::NONE;
 }
```

When going to mysite/editor/admin I get the "Ok" on a blank page.

Why does this happen? How can I fix this?

(I cleared the symfony cache and restarted apache after each change.)

Comment: It looks like problem is in action methods encapsulation. Change it to public. Btw: are you sure Your private function executAdmin realy works?

Comment: `execute*` function inside the controller must be `public`. And you have a type here: `executAdmin` Could you post the whole `actions.class.php`?

Comment: Pair programming would have solved this in no time. @j0k please add your comment as a response. That was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execute*` function inside the controller must be `public`.

Also you have a typo here: `executAdmin`. It should be `executeAdmin`.